# How do I keep track of the last folder selected by a user?

Tags: c#, directory

I thought using application settings would do the trick but I'm not getting it to work. This is what I have:

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (fbFolderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // I want to open the last folder selected by the user here.
            }
```

When the user clicks on this button, I want to open the browse window to the last folder he accessed and save it. Next time he clicks on the button, it'll automatically select that folder.

I was thinking maybe I could use user variables where I can change at run-time but I'm not getting it to work. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Also, if you're using Application Settings, don't forget to Save your changes: `Settings.Default.Save();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two places where you can find the last folder accessed by a user:

1. `Recent Files and Folders`: It can be found here: `C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Recent`
2. `Registry`: In the registry to look here: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\OpenSaveMRU`

You can use this snippet to find it:

```
public static string GetLastOpenSaveFile(string extention)
{
    RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
    string lastUsedFolder = string.Empty;
    regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\ComDlg32\\OpenSaveMRU");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(extention))
        extention = "html";

    RegistryKey myKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(extention);

    if (myKey == null && regKey.GetSubKeyNames().Length > 0)
        myKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(regKey.GetSubKeyNames()[regKey.GetSubKeyNames().Length - 2]);

    if (myKey != null)
    {
        string[] names = myKey.GetValueNames();
        if (names != null && names.Length > 0)
        {
            lastUsedFolder = (string)myKey.GetValue(names[names.Length - 2]);
        }
    }

    return lastUsedFolder;
}
```

OR

In windows XP when you press Save on a `SaveFileDialog` the directory where the file is saved, is set as the new current working directory (the one in `Environment.CurrentDirectory`).

In this way, when you reopen the `FileDialog`, it is opened on the same directory as before.

By setting `FileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true`, when you close the `FileDialog` the original working directory is restored.

In Windows Vista/Seven the behavior is always as `FileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true`.

Comment: geeze! i was thinking something a lot simpler, such as keeping track of the last folder using the project properties variables. lol.

Comment: It also depends on the OS you are working on. It works differently in different OSs.

Comment: this is for a machine using windows 7. though this could really vary :S

Comment: `RegistryKey`s are `IDisposable`, be sure to wrap them in a using block or call `.Dispose()` on them when you are done.

Answer (score 19):

Go to Settings Page, Project Designer of the project which you have created and add folder path variable inside the application. Now add below code to restore the last selected folder path.

```
FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
folderBrowser.Description = "Select a folder to extract to:";
folderBrowser.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
folderBrowser.SelectedPath = Properties.Settings.Default.Folder_Path;
//folderBrowser.SelectedPath = project_name.Properties.Settings.Default.Folder_Path;

if (folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.Folder_Path))
        Properties.Settings.Default.Folder_Path = folderBrowser.SelectedPath;

    Properties.Settings.Default.Folder_Path = folderBrowser.SelectedPath;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: More more details check this link::      
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Why this exists: if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.Folder_Path))

Answer (score 2):

Application settings can do the trick.
 [A more elaborated version is here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvb/thread/ca7ed78d-b8d9-4da3-b34c-45664e3ec89c)

> use a Setting of type string
>
> create a setting for each button and store the Path there. Then use
>   the setting as the ofd.InitialPath
>
> using the above code example, try this:
>
> right click your app name in Solution Explorer, click on the Settings
>   tab Name = Button1Path Type = String Scope = User
>
> then use this:

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fbFolderBrowser.InitialDirectory=this.Settings.Button1Path;
    if (fbFolderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // I want to open the last folder selected by the user here.
        this.Settings.Button1Path=fbFolderBrowser.SelectedPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily keep track of your last-selected folder, like this:

```
public String LastSelectedFolder;

private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fbFolderBrowser.InitialDirectory=this.Settings.Button1Path;
    if (fbFolderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Save Last selected folder.
        LastSelectedFolder = fbFolderBrowser.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I know this is a very old thread, but none of the answers point to the simplest way to re-open the file browser on user's last location.

simply define RestoreDirectory = true.
Check the example

```
var fd = new OpenFileDialog
   {
       Filter = @"All Files|*.*",
       RestoreDirectory = true,
       CheckFileExists = true
   };
```

Class OpenFileDialog api reference

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

Unless I misunderstood the intention of the post, this is by far the simplest way to achieve it. However, if you do need to print this last location, then check the other

Comment: Neat and simpe :)

Comment: This question is about the `FolderBrowserDialog`, not about `OpenFileDialog`.

Comment: @GeertBellekens, the question did not specified a particular class to be used. 
Here's the question: "I want to open the browse window to the last folder he accessed and save it. Next time he clicks on the button, it'll automatically select that folder." 
So I don't understand the downvote. Can you clarify? Besides, the solution is exactly the same using either FolderBrowserDialog or OpenFileDialog. Both have the same property which serves the purpose which is to open the dialog at the same location from previous usage.
Instead of just downvoting, should give an actual answer...

Comment: `RestoreDirectory` is at the `FileDialog` level, it's not in `FolderBrowserDialog`.